# why doesn't my basic CSS code for hide and display work?

Tags: css

Im using google chrome and i want that profile text with the background to disappear when i hover over it.  but alas it doesn't...  i'm sure im doing something fundamentally wrong.  please explain

HTML

```
<body>
<div id ="pictures">
profile
</div>
```

CSS

```
#pictures {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-color:#FCC;
}
#pictures:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I notice it's quirky in Firefox too.  Here is your code in a fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/UenGP/](http://jsfiddle.net/UenGP/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better off using `opacity: 0` to avoid any weirdness (as already explained by Danjah).

http://jsfiddle.net/UenGP/2/

```
#pictures:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Comment: that looks nice... "(as already explained by Danjah)" hrmm... guess i missed that.

Comment: I meant that he'd already explained the "flickering" weirdness. He didn't mention `opacity` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the `#pictures` element, it is then removed, therefore you are no longer hovering over it. In Firefox I see a flicker, in Chrome, perhaps the flicker is so fast you don't see it disappear only to reappear again.

Comment: ok we we have established that the code is garbage... can you tell me what i should do to fix it? even with visibility: hidden; it flickers

Comment: It would appear Google Chrome does not allow the `display` and `visibility` properties at all directly inside a `:hover` selector.